# debug does not work when opening files vs code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

hello below is a simple c program that I run with the code runner extension in vs code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   FILE* f;
   f=fopen("input.txt","rt");
   if (!f)
   {
       printf("cant open file for reading!");
       exit(1);
   }
   printf("the file was opened!");
   fclose(f);
}
```

when I run it, it manages to open the file however when I try to debug the file is never
opened.
I don't know what the problem it can recognize and edit the file but only when I go to debug the file never opens. can someone please help?

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

task.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: I suspect there's something wrong in the directory your executable/debugger refers to (please add the complete path in the `fopen` clause and try again). Why do you mention those JSON files?

Comment: Open is relative to the current directory of the process unless an absolute path is given.

Comment: @Dominique when I include the full file path it does work. the file is in the same directory as the c file.  I don't understand why when I just run the program it doesn't need the full path but when I use a debugger it suddenly needs it.

Comment: @stark both the file and the input.txt are in the same directory. when I just run the file the message "the file was opened!" is printed however when I use a debugger the message "can't open file for reading!" is printed

Comment: The process current directory has nothing to do with the location of the file that ran it.  A process run from a bash shell inherits the directory of the caller.

Comment: @stark could you please offer a way in which I could write the file "input.txt" without the full path and still debug in vs code? or link me to somewhere so I can learn about what to do to get it sorted?  sorry if I'm not so bright on the technical side ...

Comment: I don't use VS code, so not sure.  Look for cwd here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

Comment: thanks ill look into it

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and believe I found the solution.

It seems that `cwd` in `tasks.json` doesn't work properly. In my own project, I have my executable in a `build` folder within the workspace directory and set `cwd` to `${workspaceFolder}`. But I still need to have all my file paths relative to the location of my executable, not the `cwd`, or else I get failbits.

Meanwhile, and somewhat bafflingly, `cwd` in `launch.json` does work. As such, if you want to get the same outcome from both debugging and normal execution, you have to make sure that the `cwd` in `launch.json` points to your executable, not the `cwd` you used in `tasks.json`. As such, within `launch.json`, `program` and `cwd` should have the same value.

There may be some actual explanation for this but it seems like the `cwd` option in `tasks.json` is broken while in `launch.json` it is not.